# How to refetch apollo query after i redirect to page with Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I delete some resource in a page via apollo mutation:

```js
async delete () {
  await this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: orderDelete,
    variables: {
      id: this.order.id
    }
  })

  this.$emit('success')
}
```

This is the method triggered by `success` emitter:

```js
onOrderDeleted () {
  this.closeModal('modalOrderDelete')

  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.redirectToClient()
  })
},
redirectToClient () {
  this.$router.push({
    name: 'clients.show',
    params: { clientKey: this.clientKey }
  })
}
```

Here is what happen: when the page is redirected to `clients.show` the order is still being show even if i deleted it, it only updates if i refresh the whole page.

So i would like to know how i trigger a query refresh when i redirect to this page? Apollo is probably keeping data in cache and not updating it, i don't know how to update the cache only of this specific query, but all programatically because the user will be redirect via Vue Router.

Note: `clients.show` shows a list of orders, so it should update the orders removing that one i just deleted, but it just doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$apollo.mutate()` has more features than you used:

The object looks like this:

```
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: someGql,
  variables: {
    label: param1,
  },
  update: function(store, response) => {
    // how to update the store
  },
  optimisticResponse: theResponseYouExpect,
})
```

So, you sent the `gql`, but did not handle the response from that query (neither the real response from the server or the optimistic response (that you expect on success))

More on Vue Apollo mutation [here](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/mutations.html#mutations).

Comment: So what exactly i do within the `update` method? How do i update my other query that is called in another page completely different? Do you have any link explaining that?

Comment: @JoãoHamerski unfortunately no exact solutions for your exact problem. But generally: Apollo caches the data, you need to update that cache on the page change event (either by the `update` function of the mutation or by re-querying the dataset, etc.)

Comment: I'm having this error when trying to read the cache for some reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908036/error-when-reading-apollo-cache-violation-cant-find-field-field-on-object