# Error when reading apollo cache "Violation: Can't find field <field> on object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm trying to update the cache after doing a mutation with Apollo, but when i use `store.readQuery` it just throws an error:

I delete a `order` so i need to update the `orders` list in cache, i call the exactly same query `clientShow` which loads the `client` and all its `orders`, and i pass the client id that is required, but even though this error happens:

```
Invariant Violation: Can't find field orders({"first":10,"orderBy":[{"column":"CREATED_AT","order":"DESC"}]}) on object {
  "id": "45",
  "name": "Emiliano Galhardo",
  "phone": "3728051196",
  "total_owing": "4484.35",
  "shipping_company": null,
  "branch": null,
  "city": null,
  "__typename": "Client",
  "orders({\"first\":10,\"orderBy\":[{\"column\":\"CREATED_AT\",\"order\":\"DESC\"}],\"page\":1,\"where\":{}})": {
    "type": "id",
    "generated": true,
    "id": "$Client:45.orders({\"first\":10,\"orderBy\":[{\"column\":\"CREATED_AT\",\"order\":\"DESC\"}],\"page\":1,\"where\":{}})",
    "typename": "OrderPaginator"
  }
}.
```

This is the method used to delete the order and update the cache:

```js
import { clientShow } from '@/graphql/Clients.gql'

async delete () {
  await this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: orderDelete,
    variables: {
      id: this.order.id
    },
    update: (store, { data: orderDelete }) => {
      if (store.data.data.ROOT_QUERY) {
        const data = store.readQuery({
          query: clientShow,
          variables: {
            id: this.order.client.id,
            page: 1
          }
        })

        console.log(data)
      }
    }
  })

  this.$emit('success')
},
```

Here is my query:

```graphql
query clientShow (
  $id: ID! 
  $orderPage: Int!
  $orderWhere: ClientOrdersWhereWhereConditions
) {
  client (id: $id) {
    id
    name
    phone
    total_owing
    shipping_company {
      name
    }
    branch {
      city {
        name
      }
    }
    city {
      name
    }
    orders (
      first: 10 
      page: $orderPage
      orderBy: [{column: CREATED_AT order: DESC}]
      where: $orderWhere
    ) {
      paginatorInfo {
        currentPage
        perPage
        total
      } 
      
      data {
        client {
          id
        }
        code
        price
        total_paid
        quantity
        production_date
        delivery_date
        states
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when i delete a `order` calling the method `delete()` i redirect the user to another page with Vue Router, where list all orders of a given client, so the list client orders isn't being updated, i'm trying to the cache. In this client page i use this exactly query `clientShow`, so it should be cached and be avaliable in cache, and i should be able to read it again, but for some reason it just throws an error.

Comment: Hasura documentation has an interesting example: [Mutation and update cache](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/vue/optimistic-update-mutations/3.1-mutation-update-cache/) - it might help to clear up things

Comment: @muka.gergely no luck, i already used this tutorial to handle cache, it ended in this error i'm asking in the question, i'm using `lighthouse-php` to deal with graphql on server-side maybe is there something to do with it.

Comment: Instead of rewriting the cache i solved my issue setting the `fetchPolicy` attribute of the specific apollo query to `network-only` (or `no-cache` if the first not works), that way every time i redirect to the page the query is reloaded, which i think is the best way to handle my case since it asures the consistence of data.